# Lots of errors installing 'lightgbm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm getting lots of errors running `'pip install lightgbm'`.

Here is a snapshot of the errors I'm seeing.

```
ERROR: Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3012, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2806, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3003, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2806, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 524, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 108, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 47, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2727, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3014, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3023, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3005, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1419, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "C:\Users\rshuell\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1607, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\rshuell\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas-0.24.2.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

Is there a way to get this package installed?  Or, is there a workaround?  Or, maybe, another package that I can substitute for this one?

I am trying to run the sample code from the line below.

https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/feature-selector/blob/master/Feature%20Selector%20Usage.ipynb

Comment: Installation instructions at https://pypi.org/project/lightgbm/: For Windows users, VC runtime is needed if Visual Studio (2015 or newer) is not installed. Do you have one of those installed? Is your Python 64-bit?

Comment: Try installing using wheel, using the .whl file as per your environment
https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/releases